# SD Card Reader not recognized on Lenovo SL400

Tags: hardware, usb-drive

I am using elementary OS on Lenovo SL400, it has an inbuilt SD card reader. Elementary OS does not recognize an SD Card. However the same was working under Windows.

**Command**: `ls /dev/sd*`

**Output**:

```
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sda5  /dev/sda6
```

**Command**: `df -h`

**Output**:

```
S.ficheros     Tamaño Usados  Disp Uso% Montado en
/dev/sda5         24G    11G   12G  48% /
udev             980M   4,0K  980M   1% /dev
tmpfs            198M   924K  198M   1% /run
none             5,0M      0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none             990M    80K  990M   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda6        122G    69G   47G  60% /home
```

**Command**: `lsusb`

**Output**:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0a5c:2145 Broadcom Corp. BCM2045B (BDC-2.1) [Bluetooth Controller]
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 09da:022b A4Tech Co., Ltd. Wireless Mouse (Battery Free)
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 1241:1603 Belkin Keyboard
```

**Command**:

```
lspci -v
```

**Output**:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 20e0
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 20e4
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    Memory at fdc00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 5c00 [size=8]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 20e4
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at fe000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 20f0
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    I/O ports at 5880 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 20f0
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 21
    I/O ports at 5800 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 20f0
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    I/O ports at 5480 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 20f1
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at fe1fbc00 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 20f2
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    Memory at fe1f4000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: fe200000-fe2fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=0b, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00006000-0000dfff
    Memory behind bridge: fe300000-feafffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000fc700000-00000000fcefffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 4 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=0c, subordinate=0c, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: feb00000-febfffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000fcf00000-00000000fcffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 20f0
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    I/O ports at 5400 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 20f0
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    I/O ports at 5080 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 20f0
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=32]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 20f1
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at fe1fb800 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=0d, subordinate=0d, sec-latency=32
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 20f6
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: iTCO_wdt

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 20f8
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    I/O ports at 4c00 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 4880 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 4800 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 4480 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 4400 [size=32]
    Memory at fe1fb000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0035
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at fe2f0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ath5k
    Kernel modules: ath5k

0c:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2108
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    I/O ports at e800 [size=256]
    Memory at fcfff000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at fcfe0000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Expansion ROM at febf0000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```